# How to trigger batch job from the command line

Tags: batch-operations

I have a batch job that is triggered as soon as I open a specific url of my site, let's call it "http:\mysite.com\job"

The last code of that page is:

```
batch_set($batch);
batch_process('/');
```

I need to trigger it but **from another machine (CentOS)**. Tried wget and curl but without success.

Is it possible with those commands or is there another way?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you go through the advices here? https://www.drupal.org/node/873132 - If this works locally, you can easily setup a remote site alias and run the Drush command from the other machine.

Comment: I will take a look but I don't want to use Drush if possible